# AWS Transcribe error on iOS: A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-transcribe

The code below generates this error with AWS Transcribe on iOS:

> Task <1B377509-91AE-43C0-8F24-F28FE7B583AC>.<1> load failed with error
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified
>   hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x283cb55f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1B377509-91AE-43C0-8F24-F28FE7B583AC>.<1>,
>   _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <1B377509-91AE-43C0-8F24-F28FE7B583AC>.<1>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
>   be found.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://transcribe.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://transcribe.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12} [-1003]

US-West1 is a supported region for AWS Transcribe. Why is this error happening?

```
class TranscriptionNewViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    // =============================================================================================================
    // MARK: Transcription Functions
    // =============================================================================================================
    fileprivate func transcribe() {
        let fileURL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blahblahblah/Sample1.mp3"

        let jobName = "sample1"
        let languageCode = AWSTranscribeLanguageCode.enUS
        let mediaFormat = AWSTranscribeMediaFormat.mp3
        let media = AWSTranscribeMedia()
        media?.mediaFileUri = fileURL

        let jobRequest = AWSTranscribeStartTranscriptionJobRequest()
        jobRequest?.transcriptionJobName = jobName
        jobRequest?.languageCode = languageCode
        jobRequest?.mediaFormat = mediaFormat
        jobRequest?.media = media

        let transcribeClient = AWSTranscribe.default()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            transcribeClient.startTranscriptionJob(jobRequest!) { response, error in
                guard let response = response else {
                    print("Failed to start transcription")
                    return
                }

                print(response.transcriptionJob!.transcriptionJobStatus == .inProgress, "Status should have been in progress, but was \(response.transcriptionJob!.transcriptionJobStatus)")

                self.transcribeJobDidFinish()
            }
        }

        // Print status
        print("Started transcription")
    }


    fileprivate func transcribeJobDidFinish() {

    }


    // =============================================================================================================
    // MARK: IB Actions
    // =============================================================================================================
    @IBAction func transcribeButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        transcribe()
    }


    // =============================================================================================================
    // MARK: UIViewController Functions
    // =============================================================================================================
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: are you certain about the region? as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html "Amazon Transcribe" it does not seem to be the case...Also in the console I get only us-west-2 for US west regions available for this service.

Comment: @PeterPajchl please post as an answer. we're new to AWS so mistakenly though oregon was us-west-1. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, only `us-west-2` aws region for western part of US provides AWS Transcribe service. `us-west-1` is not one of them, reason why you receive the hostname lookup error.

Complete list of available endpoints for most services can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html, specifically under `Amazon Transcribe` heading.